# Trying to add quantities from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given the task of creating a database on SQL server that mirrors what we have on Access(due to the increased memory capacity). I am trying to write a query to compare the quantity of the stock levels of products across three tables and find out the difference if any. I also would like to write a query that would allow me to pull out a report of products that have had a misalignment for over 7 consecutive days. The equation for this is Table B + C = Table A. Here is my code so far:

```
CREATE TABLE EWM
(
    Date_loaded date,
    Sap_code bigint, 
    Product_description varchar(100),
    Location ntext,
    Storage_type varchar(50),
    Quantity int,
    Sap_batch ntext,
    Expiry_date date,
    Stock_type varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE USOR
(
    Date_Loaded date,
    Sap_Code bigint,
    Product_description varchar(100),
    Pack text,
    Cost_price float,
    Trade_price float,
    Stock int,
    Location text,
);

CREATE TABLE Wamas
(
    Date_Loaded date,
    Tu_barcode bigint,
    Sap_code bigint,
    Product_description varchar(100),
    Quantity int,
    LG_code varchar(100),
    Geocode text,
    Lot text,
    Expiry_date date
)

CREATE TABLE DSOR
(
    Date_Loaded datetime,
    Sap_code bigint,
    Product_description varchar(100),
    Bin_location text,
    Location varchar(50),
    Pack text,
    Units int,
    Total int,
);
```

Query attempt:

```
select 
    USOR.Sap_code, USOR.Product_description, USOR.Pack, USOR.Location,
    sum(USOR.Stock+DSOR.Total) as Total_quantity
from
    USOR
join 
    DSOR on USOR.Sap_Code = DSOR.Sap_code
where 
    USOR.Sap_Code = DSOR.Sap_code
group by 
    USOR.Sap_code
```

Currently getting an error message with the join saying

> 'USOR.Product_description' is invalid in the select list because it is
> not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Update.
Thank you all for the feedback. As I mentioned previously I am a complete beginner to SQL.
I have managed to get the outcome I was looking for by combining the quantities from the the two tables using the inner join.
I am now trying turn results of that query into a separate table which I will in another query but I'm having trouble doing so.
Here is my attempt at this:

`````
(
select USOR.Sap_Code AS Sap_code, USOR.Product_description as Product_description, USOR.Pack as Pack, USOR.Location as Location, sum(USOR.Stock+DSOR.Total) as Total_quantity 
 from USOR 
 join DSOR
on USOR.Sap_Code = DSOR.Sap_code as Total_quantity
 group by USOR.Sap_code, USOR.Product_description, USOR.Pack, USOR.Location
 ); ````

I am getting the following error message:

'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'
`````

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: BTW, no need to duplicate the JOIN conditions. You can remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: do NOT use text/ntext - those datatypes have been deprecated for 15 years. Use varchar(max) / nvarchar(max). Given the names I doubt you need to the max length, so give those columns proper lengths. Generally speaking, prices should not be stored as floating point due to the inherent imprecision of that datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
select USOR.Sap_code, USOR.Product_description, USOR.Pack, USOR.Location,
      sum(USOR.Stock+DSOR.Total) as Total_quantity
from USOR
join DSOR on USOR.Sap_Code = DSOR.Sap_code
group by USOR.Sap_code, USOR.Product_description, USOR.Pack, USOR.Location
```

Answer (score 0):

I am talking about the syntax; you are aggregating using `sum(...)` however the group by is not valid. Instead of `group by USOR.Sap_code` use

```
group by USOR.Sap_code, USOR.Product_description, USOR.Pack, USOR.Location
```

Comment: Hi Dervis, thanks for feedback this helped and I am now no longer getting this error message.

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use "GROUP BY" to aggregate, you must include in the GROUP BY clause all other fields that you selected.  You've almost got it...use the following:

```
select
    u.Sap_code
        , u.Product_description
        , u.Pack
        , u.Location
        , sum(u.Stock+d.Total) as Total_quantity
    from USOR              u
        inner join DSOR    d on u.Sap_Code = d.Sap_code
    group by
        u.Sap_code        
        , u.Product_description
        , u.Pack
        , u.Location
```

Comment: when I was posting, I had an issue with code formatting using stackoverflow.  It took me awhile to understand how to post code on this site....I'm new to it is all

Comment: You win some you lose some. But it doesn't help the OP and future viewers having 2 identical answers. Normal etiquette is to remove it.